# Data dropdown not loaded with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
                function query(){
                $leverancierVar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leverancier");
                while($record = mysql_fetch_array($leverancierVar)){
                    echo '<option value="' . $record['leverancier'] .'">' . $record['leverancier'] . '</option>';
                }
            }
```

this is my code to store all data in database in function

```
        <select id="leverancier" name="leverancier" style="width: 30%">

        <?php query() ?>

        </select>
```

this is the line of code i am using in the form to load data

[Database screenshot][1]

When I click the form dropdown button, there is [no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btJei.png) displayed. 
I am trying to solve the issue for a few hours, maybe someone with a clear look can see the mistake I made.

Edit:

I managed to get the data from the database, and displayed in a the  dropdown, however the text is not displayed in the dropdown. You can however choose a value, and the correct value will be saved in the database. [Here is a picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhQKx.png)

And here's the code I used:

```
            <?php 

        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "voorraad");

        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT leverancier from leverancier");


        echo "<select id='leverancier' name='leverancier' style='width: 30%', color='black'>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['leverancier'] ."'></option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";

        ?>
```

Comment: You aren't connected to the database.

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated in php 5.5. You better try using PDO.

Comment: `<?php query(); ?>` and try outside select

Comment: What's your PHP version? `mysql_*` functions are removed from version 7+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you're not connected to the database, probably worth looking over the connection page in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

In the manual you will probably notice some warnings about the `mysql_*` extension. That is because it is deprecated and removed in version 7 and above. What does that mean for you? Essentially you shouldn't be using the `mysql_*` extension in your code.

You should instead use `mysqli` or `PDO`

If you were going to use PDO you would connect like so:

```
$dsn      = 'mysql:dbname=<DATABASENAME>;host=<HOSTADDRESS>';
$user     = ''; // Database User
$password = ''; // Database Password.

try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // Connection failed, you may want to do something here
}
```

And then do your query like so:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM leverancier');
$statement->execute(); // Run the query.

$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo '<option value="' . $record['leverancier'] .'">' . $record['leverancier'] . '</option>';
}
```